# PARTITION BY vs ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

I was attempting this exercise:

**Employee_id is the primary key for this table. Each row of this table contains the ID of each employee and their respective team.

Write an SQL query to find the team size of each of the employees.
Return result table in any order.**

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| employee_id | int |
| team_id | int |

AND I produced this solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
employee_id
,COUNT(employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY employee_id) AS team_size

FROM employee

GROUP BY 
employee_id
,team_id
```

but this produced a weird result: {"headers": ["EMPLOYEE_ID", "TEAM_SIZE"], "values": [[4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]}...
then I removed the `ORDER BY employee_id` and then the output was as expected.

Now, I understand how PARTITION BY works in that it's counting number of employees per team but I thought ORDER BY only does ordering within the team. So how could it be that an order by is changing the output if all the employees are to be counted within the team regardless of the ordering?

Answer (score 1):

First, the query that you want does not use aggregation.  It is:

```
SELECT employee_id,
       COUNT(employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY team_id) AS team_size
FROM employee;
```

Second, the use of `ORDER BY` in a window function also adds an implicit window frame clause.  So your logic is:

```
COUNT(employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY team_id
                         ORDER BY employee_id
                         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                        )
```

This is true of *all* window functions, not only `COUNT(*)`.  So, the `COUNT()` is only counting the employee ids up to the "current" employee id.

In this case, it is equivalent to `ROW_NUMBER()` because `employee_id` is unique.  In general, it is equivalent to `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `order by` says that you want a running count of the data.  So the first row you come to in the given group will have a count of 1.  The second row will have a count of 2, etc.

This generally isn't hugely useful with the `count` analytic function.  If you want to order rows within a group, you'd generally want to use `rank`, `dense_rank`, or `row_number` rather than `count`.  On the other hand, adding an `order by` is very useful with the `sum` analytic function to get a running total.

```
COUNT(employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY employee_id) 
SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY employee_id) 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY employee_id)
```

should all give the same results (assuming `employee_id` is never `null`).  But the first two don't make a huge amount of logical sense.

Comment: Why does ORDER BY give a running count? Is this a general rule that an aggregate window function with ORDER BY will do this? Sorry I've only ever used ORDER BY in window functions to fetch first or last row of something, seems like I'm missing a key piece of info.